# Spring Boot multipart applicaition failing when reading CSV multipart input

Tags: csv, spring-boot, jackson

I have a spring boot application which expects a CSV file as input along with a request body. My application is failing with below error.

```
JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 2]
```

My Controller

```
@RestController
public class DataValidatorController {

    private static final String VALIDATE_DATA_URI ="/validatedata";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataValidatorController.class);

    private DataValidateService dataValidateService;



    public DataValidatorController(DataValidateService dataValidateService) {
        this.dataValidateService = dataValidateService;
    }



    @PostMapping(VALIDATE_DATA_URI)
    public DataValidateResponse validateData(@RequestPart("metadata") DataValidateRequest dataValidateRequest,
                                             @RequestPart("datafile") MultipartFile dataFile) throws IOException {

        logger.info("validateData() Starts");
        return dataValidateService.validateData(dataValidateRequest,dataFile);
    }

}
```

My CSV file content

name,age

person1,32

person2,33

Answer (score 0):

Have tested this code using CURL and I got 200.

#### DataValidatorController.class

```
    private static final String VALIDATE_DATA_URI ="/validatedata";

    @PostMapping(value = VALIDATE_DATA_URI)
    public ResponseEntity validateData(@RequestPart("metadata") MyPojo myPojo,
                                       @RequestPart("datafile") MultipartFile dataFile) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(String.format("Data - %s", myPojo.getId() ));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

#### MyPojo.class

```
//Used lombok

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyPojo
{
    private String id;

}
```

#### CuRL request

> curl -i -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "metadata=@test.json;type=application/json" -F "datafile=@test.csv;type=application/csv"  http://localhost:8080/validatedata

#### test.json

```
{
 "id": "1"
}
```

#### test.csv

```
name,age
person1,32
person2,33
```

Update me if you got the answer.

## EDIT

[image]

I got proper result in Postman too.

Header =>  Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Comment: im using postman to submit the request. Looks like im missing something in postman setup

Comment: Have updated the post with postman result... check the request body which you are sending.May be start with one data in the body or a string